# Push notifications not working in android 12

Tags: android, notifications, capacitor, android-api-31, android-api-30

I have a notification problem.

Since I upgraded the android api 30 to api 31, the firebase "push" notifications with ionic capacitor stopped working for android 12, they only work for android 11 api 30 or below

It works correctly with the target SDK 30, but you have to update this due to the new requirement of google play

Comment: So what is the question? follow the migration guide of Android for android 12, a new permission was added that you need to implement in order to receive push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and the solution for me was to change
`firebaseMessagingVersion` in android project from 21.0.1 (in my case) to 21.1.0
in build.gradle (capacitor-push-notifications)

```
firebaseMessagingVersion = project.hasProperty('firebaseMessagingVersion') ? rootProject.ext.firebaseMessagingVersion : '21.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked out for me, but then, when the notification is tapped the app won't open due to trampolin restrictions started on android 12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).